# Simple periodic task in celery doesn't work but no errors

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm new in Celery. I'm trying to properly configure Celery with my Django project. To test whether the celery works, I've created a periodic task which should print "periodic_task" each 2 seconds. Unfortunately it doesn't work but no error.

**1** Installed rabbitmq

**2** `Project/project/celery.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

from django.conf import settings  # noqa

app = Celery('project')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def myfunc():
    print 'periodic_task'

@app.task(bind=True)
def debudeg_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**3** `Project/project/__init__.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from .celery import app as celery_app
```

**4** `Settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'djcelery',
    ...]
...
...

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
  'schedule-name': {
                      'task': 'project.celery.myfunc',  # We are going to create a email_sending_method later in this post.
                      'schedule': timedelta(seconds=2),
                      },
  }
```

And before `python manage.py`, I run `celery -A project worker -l info`

Still can't see any "periodic_task" printed in console every 2 seconds... Do you know what to do?

EDIT CELERY CONSOLE:

```
 -------------- celery@Milwou_NB v3.1.23 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-8-6.2.9200
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         dolava:0x33d1350
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . project.celery.debudeg_task
  . project.celery.myfunc
```

**EDIT:**

After changing worker to beat, it seems to work. Something is happening each 2 seconds (changed to 5 seconds) but I can't see the results of the task. (I can put anything into the CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE, even wrong path and it doesn't raises any error..)

I changed myfunc code to:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def myfunc():
    # notifications.send_message_to_admin('sdaa','dsadasdsa')
    with open('text.txt','a') as f:
        f.write('sa')
```

But I can't see text.txt anywhere.

```
> celery -A dolava beat -l info
celery beat v3.1.23 (Cipater) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler

    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[2016-10-26 17:46:50,135: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2016-10-26 17:46:50,138: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2016-10-26 17:46:51,433: INFO/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed.

[2016-10-26 17:46:51,433: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2016-10-26 17:46:51,812: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task schedule-name (dolava_app.tasks.myfunc)
[2016-10-26 17:46:51,864: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2016-10-26 17:46:57,138: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task schedule-name (dolava_app.tasks.myfunc)
[2016-10-26 17:47:02,230: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task schedule-name (dolava_app.tasks.myfunc)
```

Comment: Is RabbitMQ service running?

Comment: @anonymous Yes, I think, it didn't work until I've installed RabbitMQ. It can be something obvious because I'm very new and very confused with celery. I've added a part of celery console at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Also take a note that, when you update the code within celery task. You need to restart the celery service in order for changes to reflect

Comment: @yes, I've restarted celery in the console (ctrl+c and celery -A project worker -l info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run

`$ celery -A project beat -l info`

Comment: This seems to help. I can see in celery console that something happens each 2 (or changed to 5) seconds. The problem is that the myfunc doesn't seem to have any effect. I've added a console output at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Oh, I run this instead of worker. When I tried to run both worker and beat at once, It worked.